# Git png file always shows as "Changes not staged for commit"

Tags: git

I just spent some time trying to figure this out. I tried nearly a dozen different solutions in stack, but nothing seems to resolve this.  In one of the posts I found, it suggested doing `git ls-files --eol`.  When I tried that, I noticed that there are 2 versions of the file, one with capitals and one with lower case:

```
i/-text w/-text attr/                   html/css/south-street/images/ui-icons_8DC262_256x240.png
i/-text w/-text attr/                   html/css/south-street/images/ui-icons_8dc262_256x240.png
```

Note: **8DC262** versus **8dc262**

macOS's file system is case insensitive.  The repo originally came from a linux system.  In fact, when I clone on linux, there are 2 files, but on my mac, there's only 1:

My mac:

```
> ls -1 html/css/south-street/images/
...
ui-icons_847e71_256x240.png
ui-icons_8dc262_256x240.png
ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
...
```

Linux:

```
> ls -1 html/css/south-street/images/
...
ui-icons_847e71_256x240.png
ui-icons_8dc262_256x240.png
ui-icons_8DC262_256x240.png
ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
...
```

So I'm not sure how to resolve this.  Is there a work around such that I don't constantly see:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   html/css/south-street/images/ui-icons_8DC262_256x240.png

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I guess I could try and remove one of the files.  I bet they're the same and the duplicate was a mistake, but regardless, I'm wondering if there's a solution that resolves the capitalization issue.

**UPDATE**: I have learned that the file was automatically generated by jQuery when selecting a theme for our website. The original author of the site, who also uses a mac, claims that he had encountered this issue in the past, had somehow resolved it, but doesn't remember how he did it.  I suspect he performs his editing remotely and never really properly diagnosed this issue.  I was editing remotely, but changed to local editing upon encountering VPN stability issues.

So my question needs further qualification: I'm a part of team development efforts, thus I don't want to implement a change that will affect the repo on github via PRs/pushes.  So I need a solution that doesn't constantly show changes **without creating a situation where I am submitting PRs that include the deletion of one of these 2 files**.  So whether it's a way to ignore differences in specific files or some other work-around... when I get down to it, I really just want to be able to perform `git add`s and `git commit`s of all changed files excluding files affected by this case-issue.  I guess I can suffer the "Changes not staged for commit", but if there was also a way to ignore these files in a `git status` command, that would be a plus.

For the time being, I'm going to create a shell function that allows me to git add/commit all changes except that file.

Comment: There's no way to do what you want.  [Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile), and as long as the files differ in contents, Git will consider them to be modified.  This is a defect in your OS, not in Git.  If you must work with repositories with files that differ only in case, reinstall your Mac with case-sensitive APFS or use a Linux system.

Comment: Windows' default file system is case insensitive too, BTW, so the only systems git apparently fully supports are the various flavors of linux. I'm glad that its documentation in the next release will at least address this conflict. While I didn't find any formal system requirements in the git documentation (in my admittedly limited search) and the case insensitivity of Windows and Mac are explicit design decisions, I agree that it could be construed as a "defect" and I fail to see why they made that decision. I'm considering a reformat, but I'm wary that that would be a problem-free solution.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it's [impossible to correctly case-fold Unicode text in a locale-insensitive way](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/), and Windows and Mac are broken when they attempt to do so.  Git will work fine for you if you're on a case-insensitive file system and don't have files differing in case, but there's no possible way for it to write both files into the system if your file system doesn't support that.  That's your OS's problem; Git's just doing the best it can given your OS's limitations.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I understood the limitation. Thanks for confirming there's no work-around. If you add the caveat/downsides of how PRs are affected, to your answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git internally is always case sensitive.  That's because traditionally, Unix systems are case sensitive, Unix file names are sequences of arbitrary bytes that need not be in any encoding, and even if you do know the encoding, it's impossible to correctly case-fold Unicode text in a locale-insensitive way.

However, Macs are by default case insensitive, so when you have two file names that differ only in case, your file system can store only one.  Git will notice that the two files are not identical, and mark one of them as modified.

If you don't want this to happen on the Mac, then you need to delete one of those files with `git rm --cached`, commit that change, and then, when the working tree is otherwise clean, run `git checkout .`.  There's no way that macOS can store two files that differ only in case unless you've formatted your file system to be case sensitive.

Note that if you do this and submit a pull request, that change will apply to everyone who works on the repository once it's merged.  That may be desired, if the repository has many Windows and Mac users, or it may be undesirable.  Regardless, this is probably not a change you just want to make locally if you can avoid it.

If this isn't your repository, you could ask the owner of it to fix that so it works nicely across systems, which they may choose to do or not.

There will be an entry for this in [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq) as of the next release using the approach I mentioned.

Comment: Is there a way to tell got that file A on my system is file B in the repo?  Like a mapping that works around this issue?

Comment: @hepcat72: no. This sort of thing has been brought up on the Git mailing list in the past, but nobody ever gets past a lot of the stumbling blocks.

Comment: Is it possible to checkout just part of a repository, say everything except one of those 2 files? And only check it out if I ever decide to modify it? Or could I tell got to ignore changes to a specific file?

Comment: A follow-up question would be... how does git even compare its version with the version I've got? What is it comparing? Is it comparing the same case-insensitive single file with git's 2 "copies" of that file, or with another single version, twice? I suspect the former. If so, how are the files saved by git?

Comment: Also, after performing your suggestion, I see `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.`. So what happens when I push a branch created off of this? I assume I'll be deleting the file in github's copy of the repo. If so, why would you suggest this solution?

Comment: I think I know what's missing here. I'm part of a team working on this repo. We're all making changes, submitting PRs, and performing code reviews. I should have qualified this in my question. I'm going to have to roll back this change so I don't end up changing the remote.

Comment: Git compares the files by hash.  If the contents are the same, then Git will not mark the file as modified; if they differ, then Git will consider them to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it turned out it was because we had enabled git lfs but had failed to commit the files (exp: .png files) that needed to be added to git lfs.

This post explains it:
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1939

What clued me in was when I ran

git reset --hard HEAD

locally - I got that odd message about a encountering a file that should've been a pointer.  Specifically:

Encountered 1 file that should have been a pointer, but wasn't:

By just committing the file - it puts it into git lfs.